# VisualForce Email Template for Experience Cloud Emails

Tags: partner-communities, visualforce-template

I'm trying to use a VisualForce email template for my Communities emails (Experience Cloud)

I'm getting errors as I haven't specified a "relatedToType" in the following:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="xxxx - Introducer Weekly Update" recipientType="User" relatedToType="">
```

What relatedtoType do i need to use for this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Riley, Welcome to SFSE! "RelatedToType" is requred if you are using any merge field in your template. Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messaging_emailTemplate.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to this - the "relatedToType" needs to be "Network"